# Верно ли согласование? побывал 1 миллион 62 тысячи человек

Tags: согласование

на сегодняшний день в музее побывал 1 миллион 62 тысячи человек - Верно ли согласование?

Answer (score 2):

Выбираем между **побывало и побывали**.

При большом количестве Розенталь в качестве варианта рекомендует  ед.  число. Но посетители "побывали", то есть посещали музей в разное время в отдельности, а в этом случае согласование во мн.числе. Также надо учитывать, что согласование по смыслу становится всё более употребительным, поэтому выбираем: **На сегодняшний день в музее побывали 1 миллион 62 тысячи человек.**

**Примечание:** **особое согласование** в ед.числе возможно для составных числительных, **оканчивающихся на "один**", да и то не всегда: в соревновании участвовал/участвовали двадцать  один студент, но: погиб двадцать один человек.